# ViennaCL on OS X: Can't copy data to GPU

Tags: opencl, viennacl

I'm just learning to work with ViennaCL. The first tries on the CPU worked fine, now I am trying to use OpenCL. However, I can't manage to get data onto the GPU - while the matrices seem to be created, they don't get any contents:

```
#define VIENNACL_WITH_OPENCL
#define VIENNACL_WITH_UBLAS 
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include "viennacl/matrix.hpp"

int main() {
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<float> data_cpu(1,1);
    data_cpu(0,0) = 1;

    viennacl::matrix<float> data_gpu(1,1);
    viennacl::copy(data_cpu, data_gpu);

    assert(data_cpu(0,0) == data_gpu(0,0));
}
```

After this, `data_gpu(0,0)` is `0` but I believe it should be `1`.

I'm compiling this with `g++ nocopy.cpp -framework OpenCL`. I am using OS X with the provided OpenCL driver.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Removing `VIENNACL_WITH_OPENCL` fixes the problem, but is not what I want.

Comment: Update: This seems to be an issue with OS X - on another (SLES) machine, it works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like (my?) OS X installation of OpenCL is somehow broken. Other, plain, OpenCL examples fail as well:

```
noname:histogram Markus$ ./histogram 
OpenCL Device Vendor = NVIDIA,  OpenCL Device Name = GeForce GT 650M,  OpenCL Device Version = OpenCL 1.1 
Image Histogram for image type = CL_RGBA, CL_UNORM_INT8: verify_histogram_results failed for indx = 0, gpu result = 0, expected result = 8204
Image dimensions: 1920 x 1080 pixels, Image type = CL_RGBA, CL_UNORM_INT8
Time to compute histogram = 0 ms
Image Histogram for image type = CL_RGBA, CL_FLOAT: verify_histogram_results failed for indx = 0, gpu result = 0, expected result = 8049
Image dimensions: 1920 x 1080 pixels, Image type = CL_RGBA, CL_FLOAT
Time to compute histogram = 0 ms
noname:histogram Markus$ pwd
/Users/Markus/Desktop/tmp/opencl-book-samples-read-only/src/Chapter_14/histogram
```